# Fastest way to find largest inscribed circle in convex quadrilateral?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, computational-geometry, quadrilateral

I'm looking for the numerically fastest algorithm to determine coordinates & radius of the largest inscribed circle of a convex quadrilateral.

I've found plenty of input on approaches for general polygons, but all of them rather numerically slow. I'm curious if there's any much simpler & faster approach for plain old convex quads.

The most promising approach I found was described in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1948356/largest-incircle-inside-a-quadrilateral-radius-calculation), based on the circle touching three sides of the quad.
However, I'm not quite sure how to actually calculate this. My initial approach was to:

1. Check all combinations of 3 adjacent sides
2. Calculate the intersection of the two bisecting lines
3. Assume that intersection point is the center of the incircle
4. Check if the circle is "valid" (doesn't extend beyond the fourth side), and get the largest circle found that way

But that doesn't work, e.g. for the quad (-1,0), (1,0), (2,1), (-2,1). The incircle's center must be at y=0.5, but none of the angle bisecting lines intersect there (unless I'm somehow miscalculating these)

Is there any reasonably easy & fast way to do this?

---

Edit: My math skills aren't good enough to prove this, but my intuition is: My approach above works IF no pair of the 3 adjacent sides I'm checking are parallel.

If on the other hand I'm processing 3 sides, and the two opposite ones of them are indeed parallel: I can assume the diameter of the inscribed circle will be the distance between those two parallel lines.
To find the center of the circle, I could get the mid point of the third (non parallel) side, and add a vector in the opposite direction of the first line with length sqrt(2)*circle radius. I'd probably still have to check if the resulting circle fully lies within the quad.

For my case above, that seems to give the correct result, but I can't really prove if this is generally correct

Comment: Are you aware that there may be no solution? Try to inscribe a circle into a rectangle 3 by 4.

Comment: I believe in this problem author means that any circle that has no points outside quadrilateral is inscribed. To @Bogey: about your example (-1,0), (1,0), (2,1), (-2,1). Bisectors of angle (-2,1)-(2,1)-(1,0) and angle (2,1)-(1,0)-(-1,0) intersect in point with $y=0.5$ which can serve as center of inscribed circle (not tangent to side (-1,0)-(-2,1)).

Comment: You can take any two adjacent angles and find point of intersection of their angle bisectors (it must exist). You will get 4 points. One of this points is center of largest circle. You can find distances from these points (possible centers) to sides of quadrilateral and mark minimal distance for every possible center (minimal distance is maximal possible radius of inscribed circle with this center). Maximum of these minimal distances is maximal radius of inscribed circle. The solution requires following calculations: 4 angle bisectors, 4 line intersections, 16 distances from point to line.

Comment: Thanks very much! As in turns out, it was the stupidest possible mistake - i've had a numerical error in my angle bisection calculation. Works very well after correcting that - thanks